# Convert value string to Date, Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting a value from a DF using max aggregation, so **I get a string and I want to convert it to Date**.
What I am doing is this:

```
var date = spark.read.parquet("data/users").select("Date").agg(max(col("Date"))).first.get(0).toString
df2 = table_read.filter("Date=" + lastDate)
```

In this way I get a variable of string type and now I want to convert it to Date type. I have been searching to do this in another answers but all I saw is to do it with DataFrames and using to_date. How can I do in this case?

**EDIT**:

*Schema*:

```
root
 |-- Date: date (nullable = false)
 |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

*Output* of `spark.read.parquet("data/users").select("Date").agg(max(col("Date"))).show`:

```
+-----------+
|max(Date)  |
+-----------+
|2019-11-10 |
+-----------+
```

Error:

```
Exception message: cannot resolve '(`Date` = ((2021 - 12) - 14))' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(`Date` = ((2021 - 12) - 14))' (date and int).; line 1 pos 0;

'Filter (Date#5488 = ((2021 - 12) - 14))
```

Comment: start by checking what you get if you remove "toString". Otherwise you may need a dateformatter. I believe the spark standard library will have support for this. Try writing DateTimeFormatter and see if it lets you import it

Comment: if I remove toString, I get type Any for this var date. Can I use DataTimeFormatter to do this?

Comment: You can use DateTimeFormatter yes. But if mck is correct, you should be able to use .getDate. I'm not sure if you can. So try it out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.getDate`, e.g.

```
var date = spark.read.parquet("data/users").select("Date").agg(max(col("Date"))).first.getDate(0)
```

To use it in a filter, you can do

```
df2 = table_read.filter(col("Date") === lastDate)
// or df2 = table_read.filter("date='" + date + "'")
```

Comment: Can you use Max on a date? Might help if you try do the whole aggregation that's trying to be done. But I think it looks right

Comment: Hi mck!
With the first option I get "Error due to data type mismatch: differeng types in '(`date` = (2019 - 11) - 14))' (date and int)

And the second option I don't understand because when I read I get a variable not a DF

Comment: Was thinking usually max/min works on numbers not on dates. But maybe it has support for it.

Comment: Edited, and I put what I do after get that value in the code that is read another table using a filter.

Comment: Ah, so `.getDate(0)` doesn't cause error, but the error appears when you put it into a filter?

Comment: Yes, is when I use that value in the filter but because is saying that is not a Date, is a Int